# Run a gitlab CI pipeline in Docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

Absolute beginner in DevOps here. I have a Gitlab repo that I would like to build and run its tests in the Gitlab pipeline CI.

So far, I'm only testing locally on my machine with a specific runner. There's a lot information out there and I'm starting to get lost with what to use and how to use it.

- How would I go about creating a container with the tools that I need ? (VS compiler, cmake, git, etc...)
- My application contains an SDK that only works on windows, so I'm not sure building on another platform would work at all, so how do I select a windows based container?
- How would I use that container in the yml file in gitlab so that I can build my solution and run my tests?

Any specific documentation links or suggestions are welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about creating a container with the tools that I need ? (VS compiler, cmake, git, etc...)

you can install those tools before the pipeline [`script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) runs. I usually do this in [`before_script`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script).

If there's large-ish packages that need to be installed on every pipeline run, I'd recommend that you make yourown image, with all the required build dependencies, push it to GitLab and then just use it as your job image.

---

> My application contains an SDK that only works on windows, so I'm not sure building on another platform would work at all, so how do I select a windows based container?

If you're using gitlab.com - [Windows runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/windows_saas_runner.html) are currently in beta, but available for use.

> SaaS runners on Windows are in [beta](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/alpha-beta-support.html#beta-features) and shouldn’t be used for production workloads.
> During this beta period, the [shared runner quota for CI/CD minutes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html) applies for groups and projects in the same manner as Linux runners. This may change when the beta period ends, as discussed in this [related issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30834).

If you're self-hosting - [setup your own runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html) on Windows.

---

> How would I use that container in the yml file in gitlab so that I can build my solution and run my tests?

This really depends on:

- previous parts (you're using GL.com / self hosted)
- how your application is built
- what infrastructure you have access to

*What I'm trying to say is that I feel like I can't give you a good answer without quite some more information*